# Unit-testing scripts in CakePHP application

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit

I have developed a deal application using CakePHP. Now I want to write the unit-scripts using PHPUnit. I have installed PHPUnit on my server and test core tests is working fine. Installed Xdebug also for code analyze. When I am going to scripts for existing application then it is not working. I am able to write the unit-script for login menthod in model. But can't write the scripts for remaining methods.

```
<?php

App::uses('User', 'Model');

class UserTest extends CakeTestCase {
    public $fixtures = array('app.user');
    public $dropTables = false;
    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
    }

    public function testLogin() {
         $result = $this->User->find('count', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                // making some assumptions about the test data here
                'email' => 'test.user@gmail.com',
                'password' => 'f1054da373ace628dc73b8ec52eb28072b074940',
            ),));
        $expected = 1;
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $result);
    }

}
?>
```

it is working well. But I am not able to write scripts for the remaining methods.

Comment: why do you use `$dropTables = false;`?

Comment: Your first test, `testLogin()` doesn't actually test any of your code. It would be useful to post an actual test method and tell us what method you can't test (or why you can't test it).

Answer (score 0):

Try using bake and bake the tests to get started with the correct testing structure:

```
cake bake test
```

This might help push you in the write direction with the way Cake expects the test to be structured. It will also create the empty methods to test all of the methods in the controller.

Can you be more specific about what is not working?